# How to add namespace url to a django-rest-framework router viewset

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-rest-framework

I would like to add a url namespace to my api router but when I do the router still looks for urls without a namespace:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'events', EventViewSet)
router.register(r'comments', CommentViewSet)

urlpatterns = patterns('apiroot.views',
                       url(r'^', include(router.urls, namespace='api')),
                       )
```

The browsable api looks for url names like `'user-list'` and `'user-detail'` still instead of `'api:user-list'` which is what I would like to have happen.

I'm assuming there is an easy fix for this (it seems like a pretty standard thing to want to do) but I can't find any solution in the django-rest-framework docs. If I'm missing something from the docs, please share a link or if I am approaching this wrong (i.e "why would you do that, it's bad practice" or whatever) please explain why or what the correct way to manage api urls would be. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a [pull request open for this currently](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/1143). Please feel free to join the discussion.

Comment: Awesome! Is @readevalprint's pull working for the most part? I want to contribute but I don't want to pollute the discussion with my ignorance of the full situation. Can you briefly summarize the status and the main issues of not yet accepting the pull?

Comment: Main reason is current lack of tests — it's adding a new behaviour and we need to cover it (and bootstrapping the test is a bit of a pain so we need decent mocking.) — My guess would be in usual circumstances it would Just Work™ — if it doesn't work for you that's useful to know too. Don't worry about polluting the discussion: Join in. :-)

Comment: I still don't figure out how to use namespaces with viewsets in DRF.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very old question and the currently accepted answer from Carlton Gibson is just a link to a pull request on GitHub.

When searching the web for using Django REST Framework routers with namespace, it comes first in the results. It seems to be the only question at SO about this topic.
Since there is no concrete answer with code example, here I'd like to add my solution.

Let's take the `EventViewSet` from the OP's question. For this viewset there should be a model class `Event` and a model serializer `EventSerializer`.
The `EventSerializer` could look like this:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    # any other fields
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        # anything else
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'view_name': 'api:event-detail'}
        }
```

That is an example for `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` which includes `url` field.

Any hyperlinked fields like `HyperlinkedIdentityField` or `HyperlinkedRelatedField`, which take `view_name` as an argument should be passed the correct view name containing the namespace, either in the declaration or through the `extra_kwargs`.
For an assumed `CommentSerializer` (corresponding to the `CommentViewSet`) it could look like:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    comments = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        view_name='api:comment-detail'
    )
```

Comment: This is a very helpful highlight and solves a problem I've been working through for a couple of days now. Also note that any FK or related fields in the model also need to be added to the extra_kwargs listing so that their hyperlinks correctly use the namespace of the router