# Django REST Framework tutorial not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to make an API for my project and I found Django REST Framework - http://django-rest-framework.org/

I tried their tutorial here http://django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart. The only diference is that my app is called api.
My problem is that when I login with my admin user I receive the following error:

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'user-list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

I tried to find a solution, but the result is that I am asking here if anyone has an idea :)

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

#not sure
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

from dajaxice.core import dajaxice_autodiscover, dajaxice_config
dajaxice_autodiscover()

js_info_dict = {
    'packages': ('cards',),
}

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', include('cards.urls', namespace='cards')),
    # url(r'^giftycards/', include('giftycards.foo.urls')),
    url(r'^cards/', include('cards.urls', namespace='cards')),
    url(r'^api/', include('api.urls', namespace='api')),


    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(dajaxice_config.dajaxice_url, include('dajaxice.urls')),

    # REST API
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),

    # Internationalization urls
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    url(r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog', js_info_dict),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT }),

)
```

api/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from api import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'groups', views.GroupViewSet)

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browseable API.
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
)
```

Here is the full stack trace:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:1238/api/

Django Version: 1.5.4
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'dajaxice',
 'rest_framework',
 'api',
 'cards')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/valentin/Documents/Dev/giftycards/libs/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/valentin/Documents/Dev/giftycards/libs/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/valentin/Documents/Dev/giftycards/libs/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  77.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/valentin/Documents/Dev/giftycards/libs/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  399.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/home/valentin/Documents/Dev/giftycards/libs/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  396.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/valentin/Documents/Dev/giftycards/libs/rest_framework/routers.py" in get
  254.                     ret[key] = reverse(url_name, request=request, format=format)
File "/home/valentin/Documents/Dev/giftycards/libs/rest_framework/reverse.py" in reverse
  17.     url = django_reverse(viewname, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, **extra)
File "/home/valentin/Documents/Dev/giftycards/libs/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  496.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "/home/valentin/Documents/Dev/giftycards/libs/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  416.                 "arguments '%s' not found." % (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /api/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'user-list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Comment: Can you post your urls.py? Looks like you've left out the route for your 'user-list' view.

Comment: I added it to the main post. I mentioned that the difference from the tutorial is that my app name is api, not quickstart.

Comment: I think you need to move your api-auth url pattern out of your app-level urls.py file and into your project-level urls.py file.

Answer (score 7):

This is an issue with DRF not handling namespaced urls correctly and therefore not allowing to handle your use case,  please check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612398/how-to-add-namespace-url-to-a-django-rest-framework-router-viewset) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with the tutorial, I solved it specifing a [URL pattern name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) for the url (notice the `name` parameter):

```
url(r'^users/$', views.UserList.as_view(), name='users')
```

And then using that instead of the python path:

```
def api_root(request, format=None):
return Response({
    'users': reverse('users', request=request, format=format)
})
```